# Can not save file using the below python code. Error: numpy.ndarray object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pylab
import pymorph
import mahotas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Image

from scipy import ndimage
from pymorph import regmax
from PIL import Image




path='all_images'


for file in os.listdir(path):
    current = os.path.join(path, file)
    extension = os.path.splitext(current)[-1]
    fileType = extension.upper()
    print(current)

    if os.path.isfile(current):
        img = mahotas.imread(current)
        imgf = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img, 8)
        pylab.gray()
        imgf.save('dnaa.gif')
```

Can not save file using the below python code. Error: numpy.ndarray object has no attribute 'save'. Can anyone help how to save file using pylab. I guss the last line of the code has some issue.

Comment: In the future it is better to include the full trace back.

Answer (score 3):

Use `mahotas.imsave('dnaa.gif', imgf)` instead. The NumPy array you get from `gaussian_filter` doesn't have save functionality built in.